# qt layout()->setSizeConstraint

Tags: qt

I have a problem with the layout () in Qt 5.
I want to make a dynamic variable dialog.
![enter image description here][1]
Below is the code for the constructor:

```
SortDialog :: SortDialog (QWidget * parent)
     : QDialog (parent)
{
     setupUi (this);

     SecondaryGroupBox-> hide ();
     TertiaryGroupBox-> hide ();
     layout () -> setSizeConstraint (QLayout :: SetFixedSize);
     setColumnRange ('A', 'Z');
}
```

The project is built successfully, but when you start receiving a signal from the operating system.

```
Signal: SIGSEGV
Purpose: Segmentation fault
```

If you delete a row

```
layout () -> setSizeConstraint (QLayout :: SetFixedSize);
```

The program works.
Please, help me.
P.s.:This is an example from the book c++ GUI Programmming with Qt 4 (page 31)

Comment: Does your dialog actually have a layout?

Comment: Segmentation faults are caused when you address memory that's out of scope in general. You'd be best off running it through a debugger and finding which specific line it's crashing on.

Comment: Why the parenthesis at layout? layout() ??

Answer (score 4):

I was having the same problem.
I just solved it.
Probably you don't want the answer after two years, but I really want to write about this somewhere, because there is nothing about this little issue on the web.

The problem was that Qt Designer didn't generate code to set dialog's layout.
I just opened ui_sortdialog.h and found that out of SortDialog a widget was created. Than with this widget a layout would be created. The layout is called `gridLayout_4`, and every widget and layout of the form are added to this one. When I added to function `retranslateUi` line `SortDialog->setLayout(gridLayout_4);` everything worked. Generated code created layout and did everything what needed to be done, but it left SortDialog without any reference to the layout, therefore `layout()` returned zero.

Answer (score 2):

That's because you didn't create a layout.

Go back to designer and click the form and choose lay out in grid.

If you don't do this, the layout would be 0 and the program will crash.

Comment: short and sweet! Thanks, was exactly the issue for me!

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a layout, like QVBoxLayout.

```
QVBoxLayout *layout = new QVBoxLayout;
layout->setSizeConstraint (QLayout :: SetFixedSize);
setLayout(layout);
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this with changing in Designer Form. Make sure that the layout in the Qt Designer is good. Especially "Form -> Adjust Size" at the end. (in the book page 33; creating a "Form-> Lay Out in a Grid"). Use the original code from the book.